How to validate token without kid

Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenSignatureKeyNotFoundException: 'IDX10503: Signature validation failed. Token does not have a kid. Keys tried: '[PII of type 'System.Text.StringBuilder' is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'. Number of keys in TokenValidationParameters: '1'.
Number of keys in Configuration: '0'.
Exceptions caught:
'[PII of type 'System.Text.StringBuilder' is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'.
token: '[PII of type 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityToken' is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'. See https://aka.ms/IDX10503 for details.'

This was the exception I get; I want to validate token without giving kid in header or in claim.
Is this possible to do?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The "kid" is used to resolve the IssuerSigningKey from a key list which fetched from issuer's metadata endpoint. Such as following:
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>
    {
        
        builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {


            IssuerSigningKeyResolver = (token, securityToken, kid, validationParameters) =>
            {
                // Custom logic to resolve the signing key
                var keys = GetKeysFromMetadataEndpoint(validationParameters.ValidIssuer);
                var key = keys.FirstOrDefault(k => k.KeyId == kid);
                return new List<SecurityKey> { key };
            }
        };


IEnumerable<SecurityKey> GetKeysFromMetadataEndpoint(string issuer)
{
    // Fetch keys from the issuer's metadata endpoint
    // For example, use HttpClient to get the JWKS and parse it
    return new List<SecurityKey>();
}

So this kid cannot be skip only if you can return the correct "key" by yourself.
An easy way to skip the kid is simply disable the "IssuerSigningKey" validation. But you should consider the security impact.
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false
        }

